# Firebase functions trying to send a notification fails

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to do the following thing. I have my database like this

```
clients
|___clientnumber: 4
|___name1
    |_device_token: kJ-aguwn7sSHsjKSL....
    |_notificationtrigger: 8
```

What I want to do is that when a client puts a number in my app inside his node "name1" it will trigger a notification when clientnumber is 8 , so, client number will be 4, then 5, then 6 and so on till 8, when it hits 8 I wrote this function in order to send the user a notification telling him that the clientnumber 8 is ready.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendClientesNotification = functions.database.ref('/clients/clientnumber')
    .onWrite((snapshot, context) => {

        const newClient = snapshot.after.val();
        const oldClient = snapshot.before.val();
        console.log('New client: '+newClient);
        console.log('Old client: '+oldClient);

            // get the user device token
      const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database()
      .ref(`/clients/name1/device_token`).once('value');

      const getClientNotificationTrigger = admin.database()
      .ref(`/clients/name1/notificationtrigger`).once('value');


      //I use a promise to get the values above and return, and then I create the notification
      return Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise, getClientNotificationTrigger]).then(results => {

        const devicetoken = results[0].val();
        const clientNumberTrigger = results[1].val();

        console.log('New notification for '+devicetoken+' for the number '+clientNumberTrigger);

        if(clientNumberTrigger = newClient){
            const payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: "Alert",
                    body: "alert triggered",
                    icon: "default",
                    sound:"default",
                    vibrate:"true"
                }
            };
        }

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(devicetoken, payload);

      });

    });
```

Now, I will explain what I'm doing right here.

First I'm pointing to the reference clientnumber and successfully getting the value before and after it changes here

```
 const newClient = snapshot.after.val();
            const oldClient = snapshot.before.val();
            console.log('New client: '+newClient);
            console.log('Turno anterior: '+oldClient);
```

then I'm querying the values inside my client in order to have **device_token** and then **notificationtrigger** and using a promise to get the two values, comparing if they are identically and then returning a notification with the current user device_token

The errors I'm facing are this two

[image]

The first one I think is from this line

```
const clientNumberTrigger = results[1].val();
```

and the second one I don't know why is happening, I think that I need to add a conditional expression before my if statment

I'm starting up with firebase functions and slowly learning some javascript in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the error says: you are trying to compare two values using a single equals symbol (=) while you should use three instead:

switch this:

```
if(clientNumberTrigger = newClient) { ... }
```

to this:

```
if(clientNumberTrigger === newClient) { ... }
```

and at least this error should be gone.

Comment: Oh ! what a mistake , thanks so much @frapeti , now it is deploying and working as intended !